# iim iMacros Frame Refesh

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I am having a problem with my frame not refreshing & grabbing all the FRAMENAMES I need. I was wondering if there was a way to refresh the frames in iim, or if I should just make a js method.. I have tried refreshing the page before using the method and calling two different iim's also I have tried a js method with `parent.frames['iframes'].location.reload();` Neither are working. The only way is I call `frameName()` out side of the loop, which is useless, because I need to open and close multiple frames through out the loops life. Lastly when it is out of the loop and I get the right frame names then when call it in the iim it is either undefined or an empty string. If anyone could help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 while (i < StoreData.length){
  openAndExtract = "Code: ";
  openAndExtract += "TAB T=1" + NewLine;
  openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME="+"ext-comp-1006" + NewLine;
  openAndExtract += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:" +StoreData [i] + NewLine;
  openAndExtract += "WAIT SECONDS = 7" + NewLine;
  openAndExtract += "FRAME NAME=" + frameName() + NewLine;
  PlayMacro = iimPlay(openAndExtractCase);
  i++;
 }
```